# What does 連ツイ mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

I'm starting to read some images that talk about tail holes in clothing, for anthropomorphic animals, and I'm already stuck on the first sentence.

> しっぽ穴とその周辺についての**連ツイ**のまとめです。

What does 連ツイ mean in this sentence? 連 by itself means "group," but I'm not sure how that fits into the sentence.

Without it, I translate it as: **This is a summary of the tail hole and its surroundings.**

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48306/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Japanese language, shortening the word is common(ex ファミコン from ファミリー・コンピューター: family computer, スマホ from スマートフォン: smartphone).

So, 「連ツイ」should be 「連続ツイート」: a series of tweet, successive tweet, etc.

Probably the author is not saying a series of tweets are already categorized by some characteristics. Therefore,  I think "group" is bit off here.

The author would like to just summarize the ideas regarding the phenomenon of「しっぽ穴{あな}」: tail-hole in the clothes.

Answer (score 2):

It's short for 連続ツイート, or successive tweets (posted by a single user about a certain topic).