# Creating abbreviations for expressions

Tags: grammar, morphology

From the Wikipedia page of Nissin Foods:

> the name 'Nissin' originates as an abbreviated form of the expression 「日々清らかに豊かな味をつくる」 (Hibi kiyoraka ni yutakana aji o tsukuru),
> coined by company founder Momofuku Ando, and representing his desire for the company. The expression can be loosely translated as "Day after day purely create great taste".

How are abbreviations created in Japanese? Don't they have to pick pieces of the original expression like FYI meaning 'For your information'? Or did the they actually mean something akin an alias? Like saying 'Ford stands for tradition and reliability' (but it's no abbreviation of these words)?

Comment: Nissin is written as 日清. Perhaps you can see how that picks pieces of the original expression.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48306/9831

Answer (score 1):

日々 清らかに(ひび きよらかに)
They just pick up two kanji.
日清(にっしん)
There aren't words 日清. They just created.